# App SDK 2.0 - "Invalid Model Type"

Tags: rally

When running queries which worked perfectly in previous version of the App SDK, I am now getting error messages regarding an invalid model type specification.

[image]

The two model types which I have received errors on so far are "PortfolioItem" and "Project".

I can force the WSAPI to use version 1.43, which solved the problem, but I would like the use the latest version available if at all possible.

Comment: Under further inspection, this only happens when using the app-debug.html file. If I run the code in Rally, things seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Developing externally using the App-debug.html is the preferred manner of developing apps so we'd like to get this fixed.  I am unable to reproduce it locally.  From your stack trace it seems like the call timed out.  Could you provide a little code that demonstrates the problem?  Also, what browser?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a defect in the 2.0rc1 release of the SDK.  I'll file a defect and report back when there is a resolution and/or more information.